# Converting types when using play json writes

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Following on from this question [Applying conversion to play framework json element before applying to class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662882/applying-conversion-to-play-framework-json-element-before-applying-to-class)

I have a Date object which I want to be written to a string in json in a specific format.

```
implicit val tokenWrites: Writes[Token] = (
  (JsPath \ "creation_date").write[Date] and
  (JsPath \ "expires").writeNullable[Date]
)(unlift(Token.unapply))
```

Which I want to be json'ed as:

```
"creation_date": "2014-05-22T08:05:57.556385+00:00"
```

To convert the string to a Date I have used:

```
def strToDate(string2: String): Date = {
  val df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
  df2.parse(string2);
}
```

And then mapped in the reads, but this doesn't seem to be possible with a write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow definition of `write`

```
def write[T](implicit w: Writes[T])
```

you can create own `Writes[T]` and use it.

For example

```
object dateWrite extends Writes[Date] {
  override def writes(o: Date): JsValue = JsString("some formatted date")
}
```

will write `o:Date` to `JsString("some formatted date")` (you can use own format: Date => JsValue), and then use own `Writes[T]` in `write`:

```
implicit val tokenWrites: Writes[Token] = (
  (JsPath \ "creation_date").write[Date](dateWrite) and
    (JsPath \ "expires").writeNullable[Date](dateWrite)
  ) (unlift(Token.unapply))
```

As a result

```
tokenWrites.writes(Token(new Date(), Some(new Date())))
```

will be

```
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"creation_date":"some formatted date","expires":"some formatted date"}
```

Comment: So, I am doing as you suggest and have:

    object dateWrite extends Writes[Date] {
      override def writes(date: Date): JsValue = {
        val df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX");
        JsString(df2.format(date))
      }
    }

    implicit val tokenWrites: Writes[Token] = (
      (JsPath \ "creation_date").write[Date](dateWrite) and
      (JsPath \ "expires").writeNullable[Date](dateWrite)
    ) (unlift(Token.unapply))

But in my tests still fail as the input and output dont match?

Comment: I use your dateWrite and result of `tokenWrites.writes(Token(new Date(), Some(new Date())))` is `res2: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"creation_date":"2016-02-27T18:56:52.000258+03:00","expires":"2016-02-27T18:56:52.000258+03:00"}`. So, `Writes` is working. How do you test input and output?